# If $H \leq G$ and $\alpha \in Aut(G),$ prove that H isomorphic to $H^{\alpha}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H \leq G$ and $\alpha \in Aut(G),$ prove that H isomorphic to $H^{\alpha}.$

Could anyone give me a hint for the function that I will use?

Comment: How is $H^{\alpha}$ defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the restriction of an automorphism of any algebraic structure $\phi: A \rightarrow A$ to any sub-structure of $A$.  Given that an automorphism is itself injective, surjective, and structure-preserving, what can be said about this restriction?

Comment: What do you mean by "Consider the restriction of an automorphism of an algebraic structure ϕ:A→A to any sub-structure of A."?

Comment: If we have this automorphism $\phi$ and a sub-structure $B \subset A$, the restriction to $B$ is defined as $\tau:B \rightarrow B$ where $\tau(b) = \phi(b)$ for all $b \in B$.  I.e. it's the same as $\phi$ but with a "restricted" domain.